# lapply() when function returns NULL

Tags: r

Is there a method to stop `lapply()` from returning NULL values for each element of the list when a function doesn't have a `return()`.

Here's a pretty basic example:

```
x <- function(x) {
return(NULL) }

a.list <- list(a=1,b=2,c=3)

lapply(a.list, x)
```

The output is:

```
$a
NULL

$b
NULL

$c
NULL
```

My goal is to not have that output, at all.

Update: my usage case is as follows. I'm using `lapply()` to pump out `xtable()` text and I'm `sink()`'ing it to an Rnw file. So this NULL output is bugging up my automation.

Comment: I wrap `apply` in `invisible` when I'm writing to `sink`.

Comment: Put that as an answer so I can checkmark it :) It's exactly what I was asking for.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

two options come to mind:

Either

```
trash_can <- lapply(a.list, x)
```

or

```
invisible(lapply(a.list, x))
```

The first one makes me wonder if there is an analog of Linux's `/dev/null` in `R` that you can use to redirect stuff that you don't want. The only problem with creating the variable `trash_can` is that it will hang around and use up memory unless you `rm(trash_can)`. But I don't think that's a problem here.

Comment: `invisible()` as suggested by Roman, was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 9):

You did

```
R> x <- function(x) { return(NULL) }
R> a.list <- list(a=1,b=2,c=3)
R> res <- lapply(a.list, x)
R> res
$a
NULL

$b
NULL

$c
NULL

R>
```

and as as you asked `lapply` to sweep over all elements of the list, you can hardly complain you get results (in `res`) for all elements of `a.list`.  That is correct.

But what nice about the `NULL` values, though, is that it is trivial to have them skipped *in the next aggregation step*:

```
R> do.call(rbind, res)
NULL
R>
```

So I've mostly used this approach of returning `NULL` when the data had an issue or another irregularity arose, as you can easily aggregate the 'good' results afterwards.

Comment: No complaint about functionality. Just looking to get the results in a different way. Thanks for the pointer to `do.call()`

Answer (score 5):

You could just do

```
a.list <- a.list[!sapply(a.list, is.null)]
```

Comment: I'm not trying to remove NULL elements from my list. I'm trying to stop the output from a function that returns NULL as shown above.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to do that, short of replacing `lapply` with a loop and testing each result before incrementing the list. This will get you to the same endpoint, though.

Comment: Also sapply is dangerous to program with.

Comment: @hadley why is that? My guess: because it might try to coerce a list into a vector that could cause problems?

Comment: It's dangerous to program with because you don't know what output it will give you - this is typically problematic when the input is zero length. `vapply` is uniformly better.

Comment: Alternatively, `Filter(length, a.list)` will return components that do not have 0 length.

Comment: @hadley: Is there any way to prevent `vapply` from returning anything?

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to take a look at `l_ply` from the `plyr` package. It is supposed to return nothing, and it has all the properties of `lapply`, plus some more.

Answer (score 1):

These days I would use `purrr::walk` since it is meant to do a function for the side effect without returning a result